# Inequality $a^2b^2+2(a+b)\geq 4ab+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $a,b\geq 1/2$. Prove that $$a^2b^2+2(a+b)\geq 4ab+1.$$

We know that $(ab-1)^2\geq 0$ implies $a^2b^2+1\geq 2ab$, so the inequality reduces to $2(a+b)\geq 2ab+2$, or $a+b\geq ab+1$. But this is equivalent to $(a-1)(b-1)\leq 0$, which is not true. How can we fix it?

Comment: The slightly (but *only* slightly) flippant answer is: Don't do that, then. To be less flippant, what you have discovered is that the inequality you used is to rough an estimate to work. So you'll need to abandon that approach and try something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $(2a-1)(2b-1)=4ab-2(a+b)+1$.